# Sql Charindex separate words

Tags: sql, t-sql

I detect and process the first and second words of the written sentence. What I want to do is detect and process the third and fourth words. There are examples and explanations in the picture. Thanks for your answers.

```
            Declare
        @FirstWord varchar(16),
        @SecondWord varchar(16),
        @ThirdWord varchar(16),
        @FourthWord varchar(16)

SET @FirstWord = LEFT(@Message,LEN(@Message)-CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@Message),1)) 
SET @SecondWord = CAST(RIGHT(@Message,LEN(@Message)-CHARINDEX(' ',@Message,1)) as int)

/* how do i catch the third and fourth word 


SET @ThirdWord =  ??????????????????? 
SET @FourthWord =  ??????????????????? 
*/

IF @FirstWord = 'hello' and @SecondWord = 1
begin
INSERT INTO  [dbo].[_Message]  (Message) Values ('The first word you wrote = '+Convert (varchar(16), @FirstWord)+' The second word you type = '+Convert (varchar(16), @SecondWord)+' ') 
end
```

What needs to be done is to learn the third and fourth word in the same way.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server (tsql)?

Comment: Pictures are useless for others to be able to duplicate your code without laboriously transcribing that which you already have in a more convenient form. They're also bad for accessibility. Please include the code, *as code*, in the question.

Comment: This *looks* like T-SQL (so SQL Server) *not* MySQL to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using `reverse()` if you want the *first* words in the message.  In any case, you can just pop off the first word and repeat this process for each word:

```
declare @rest varchar(max);
set @rest = @message;

select @firstword = left(@rest, charindex(' ', @rest + ' ') - 1);
set @rest = stuff(@rest, 1, charindex(' ', @rest), '');

select @secondword = left(@rest, charindex(' ', @rest + ' ') - 1);
set @rest = stuff(@rest, 1, charindex(' ', @rest), '');

select @thirdword = left(@rest, charindex(' ', @rest + ' ') - 1);
set @rest = stuff(@rest, 1, charindex(' ', @rest), '');

select @fourthword = left(@rest, charindex(' ', @rest + ' ') - 1);
set @rest = stuff(@rest, 1, charindex(' ', @rest), '');

select @firstword, @secondword, @thirdword, @fourthword;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fb5db1e024ab7e28b377b066b3ac156f) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that this type of operation is suspicious.  First, SQL Server is not the best tool for parsing strings.  And if you are going to split a `@message`, you should probably split all the words and store the results in a temporary table of some sort.  Then you can process the table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, that's exactly what I was looking for